# How to filter user input in C / Prevent the user from typing unwanted characters

Tags: c, input, filter

Let's say that you are getting user input but there are certain characters that you do not want to allow the users to type (i.e. you don't want any **spaces** or **commas** from your user input).

```
char c, myString[1000];

for(int i = 0; (c = getchar()) != '\n'; i++)
   myString[i] = c;

// myString, without any spaces or commas
printf("%s", myString);
```

How would you go about solving this?

If it is not possible to prevent the user from typing certain characters, then how can they be filtered once the input is received?

**EDIT**

Just like how `scanf` skim through spaces automatically when input is being put into a string, I was simply asking if a more elegant solution like that exists, or even if it is possible to prevent the user from typing such unwanted characters in the first place.

Comment: I wasn't necessarily asking about how to filter out the input once it is received, instead, I asked if there was any way to prevent the user from typing the unwanted input in the first place.

Comment: No, there is not.  Some platforms (e.g. Windows) might have platform-specific features to do things like that, but standard C can't do it.